# Execution failed for task ':tasks'

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

> Could not create task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
> No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARN�NG

Can you help me

gave an error during start the project

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which says to include the source of your code, not just the error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

i try kotlin lastest version. this method worked for me

kotlinVersion = '1.9.0'

classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0"